# Convert C# HttpWebRequest in PHP cURL Request

Tags: c#, php, curl, httpwebrequest

I'm new with cURL, I succeeded with my first request but now I'm stuck. I have the right request in C# but I don't know how to convert the second in cURL PHP.

Here is the HttpWebRequest:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://www.google.fr"));
request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
request.Headers["X-343-Authorization-WLID"] = "v1=" + accessToken;
request.Accept = "application/json";
```

`accessToken` is a `string` variable of course.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers for how to do headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the three base curl_setopt calls you'll need to make.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"$website");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'application/json');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-343-Authorization-WLID:v1=$accesstoken"));
```

You might want to add follow_location and return_transfer, but I don't know exactly what you're doing.  Both of those options are listed in the [curl_setopt](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt) documentation.

That page should have enough examples to get you going.