# Do ETags help reduce YouTube API quota usage?

Tags: http, youtube-api

I'm wondering if the use of ETags with the YouTube DATA API has any beneficial effect on quota usage? An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752421/youtube-api-v3-and-etag) implies that they will not count against your quota, but I can't find anything like that in the [official documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752421/youtube-api-v3-and-etag).

Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1):

AS I understand the [quota usage document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota), every API call (even invalid ones) incur 1 point against your quota; additional quota charges are assessed based on the parts returned, the actions performed, etc. So it seems logical that using etags will still use up 1 point per call, but won't incur any of the other read/write charges (since nothing else is returned) when the resource hasn't been modified. Of course, if the resource has been modified, you'll get the full resource back and have full quota charges again.

You're right, though, that no where is this explicitly stated.