# Which youtuve v3 api not supporting etag

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, etag

I am using youtuve v3 `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search` api to get the list of videos in a channel.

Also, trying to use etag to use caching to avoid quota limit in youtube api. I am always get different etag for each request.

So i would like to know is this search api support etag caching?. I am using php curl to get the results.

eg:

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'If-None-Match: "'.$eTag.'"' );

        $curl_exec = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: How will using the Etag help you avoid quota?

Comment: As per youtube doc ETag change only when there is a change in the response data. otherwise it respond with a 304 status. This will help to use the cached response. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752421/youtube-api-v3-and-etag