# Youtube Data API - etags interaction with quota

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a question in regards to how etags and quota usage interact.

I've been looking into threads that speak on both (for example [Youtube API V3 and Etag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752421/youtube-api-v3-and-etag)) and I'm not sure I understand exactly how e-tags interact with Quota Usage.

For example for [*PlaylistItems.list*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?hl=pt-br) or [*Videos.list*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?hl=pt-br) (consumes 1 quota per call)

- (1) Will 1 quota always be consumed even if I made a call and the content was cached? (status 304 is received, will that consume quota?)
- (2) or will 1 quota be consumed only when the etag becomes stale and the resource returned has updated (or when it's the first time obtaining the resource)?

Which of these scenarios would be true? From the thread aforementioned it would look like that scenario (1) is the truth

Answer (score 0):

> All API requests, including invalid requests, incur a quota cost of at least one point.

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

So I don't think that etag has something to do here (even if it should).

Comment: That is what I think as well. But discussions I read on this caused me to doubt which is the truth.

Comment: You can still try on your one and look at your quota evolution from https://console.cloud.google.com