# Paypal IPN return HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Since October 1st, my IPN file is not working. The path and the file is

When i try my  in the IPN Simulator, i have this informations in my log :

```
[2015-10-08 11:20 Europe/Paris] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
User-Agent: company-name
Content-Length: 913
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Thu+Oct+08+2015+10%3A59%3A11+GMT%2B0200+%28CEST%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=893479947&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AJNFZNUcg.BzCLg6LJUDCBr2KwOSAHINNAeY617BPXbByr2DJsge-6hL

[2015-10-08 11:20 Europe/Paris] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Server: BigIP
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 08 Oct 2015 09:20:22 GMT
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000
```

I don't understand why i have a [2015-10-08 11:20 Europe/Paris] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

The URL is correct, because i have log infos. I found that i have to parse a User-Agent in this topic : [Why do I keep getting a 403 forbidden with PayPal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013941/why-do-i-keep-getting-a-403-forbidden-with-paypal)

I do it, but the 403 is still here, and i don't know why.

If you have any idea that can help me , I will Would be grateful !

Thanks,
Jeremy.

Comment: Find the solution. In the IPN file, i change "https://paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" by "https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" and it's works !

Comment: Yes it's explained here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNImplementation/
Previously it was www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr and for me it suddenly changed today without any notice !!