# paypal plus, going live

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've integrated `paypal plus` on my site according to this tutorial https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/de_DE/downloads/PayPal-PLUS-IntegrationGuide.pdf

all work pretty fine on `sandbox` mode, but when I try go to `live`, I've got an error `Forbidden`, when displaying payment wall. In firebug `NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - https://www.paypal.com/paymentwall/payment-selection`. It looks like this http://joxi.ru/VrwVoeMIKDg5QA

my `php` code for getting `approval url`

```
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        Yii::app()->params['paypal']['ClientID'],     // ClientID
        Yii::app()->params['paypal']['ClientSecret']      // ClientSecret
    )
);

$apiContext->setConfig(
      array(
        'mode' => 'live',                        
      )
);  

$item1 = new \PayPal\Api\Item();
$item1->setName('Test item')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice(1);

$itemList = new \PayPal\Api\ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1));

$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD');
$amount->setTotal('1');

$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);
$transaction->setItemList($itemList);
$transaction->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());
$transaction->setDescription('Payment for fashion.com');

$host = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$redirectUrl = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrl->setReturnUrl($host . '/shop/pay');
$redirectUrl->setCancelUrl($host . '/shop/pay');

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrl);
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

$payment = $payment->create($apiContext);

$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

Then I using it in `js`

```
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js"></script>
<script>
    PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
        "approvalUrl": "<?=$approvalUrl?>",
        "placeholder": "ppplus",
        "mode": "live",
        "country": "DE",
        "buttonLocation": "outside",
        "disableContinue": "continueButton",
        "enableContinue": "continueButton",
        "showLoadingIndicator": true,
        onContinue: function () {
        }
    });
</script>
<div id="ppplus"></div>
```

Paypal header in response

```
Paypal-Debug-Id:    bfd9325f785dd, bfd9325f785dd
```

Our client told us that he got in touch with the `paypal` and activate his account for `paypal plus`. Maybe we had some errors in out code? Or maybe we are trying to do this in a country that restricted for paypal?

Update

I use live credentials. And in request to the `www.paypal.com/paymentwall/payment-selection` there is `User-Agent` header -

```
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
```

And I'm using standart paypal api `https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I keep getting a 403 forbidden with PayPal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013941/why-do-i-keep-getting-a-403-forbidden-with-paypal)

Comment: @lonut necula I guess it's not duplicated. It's a different case. Currently, I am facing the same issue. The link you are referring to is different than this issue.

Comment: @sam3434 btw, how did you overcome the issue? Was that working?

Answer (score -3):

Change your code from:

```
$apiContext->setConfig(
  array(
    'mode' => 'live',                        
  )
);
```

To:

```
$apiContext->setConfig(
  array(
    'mode' => 'live'                      
  )
);
```

**Note: After 'live' no COMMA**

Comment: This makes no sense