# Token authentication with PHP REST client

Tags: php, rest, guzzle, httpful

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a request to a REST api using some PHP client.

```
Authorization: Token token="CREDENTIALS"
```

I can successfully curl it by using

```
$ curl -H 'Authorization: Token token="CREDENTIALS" https://uriexample.com
```

But I can't figure out a way to set this header in any PHP client I tried (Guzzle and Httpful).

Would anyone know how can I do this with ANY PHP client? I just don't wanna code this client from scratch :(

Comment: built in curl library is all you need

Comment: @nogad if you can illustrate this with an example that can be a good answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30600026/2160958

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331224/how-to-include-authorization-header-in-curl-post-http-request-in-php

Answer (score 1):

The Guzzle docs have loads of examples if you dig into them a little.
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#making-a-request
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#headers

```
<?php

// Create HTTP client with headers for all requests
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://uriexample.com',
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Token token="CREDENTIALS"',
    ],
]);

// Dispatch GET request
$client->request('GET', '/');


// OR


// Create HTTP client
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://uriexample.com',
]);

// Dispatch GET request with specific headers
$client->request('GET', '/', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Token token="CREDENTIALS"',
    ],
]);
```