# Using Curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am working on a project, to help me learn how to use `curl` through `PHP`. I am attempting to get data from the [`Twitch-API`](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API) using my own account for testing.

I have successfully authenticated my account with my domain by using:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&scope=user_read+channel_read+channel_subscriptions+user_subscriptions+channel_check_subscription&state=...
```

I have removed `client_id`, `redirect_uri` and `state` to show the link I used.

Once successfully authenticated it returns back to a domain that I specify (`redirect_uri`), once it gets back to that domain the website only knows the authentication key that is generated once accepted by the user, from twitch.

Example auth: `3ofbaoidzkym72ntjua1gmrr66o0nd`

Now I would like to be able to get the username of the user, [there is documentation on it](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/users.md):

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' -H 'Authorization: OAuth <access_token>' \
-X GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/user
```

I am attempting to do this in PHP, but I don't understand the curl functions... Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['code']) && isset($_GET['scope'])) { ?>

<pre>
<?php
    $auth = $_GET['code'];
    $twitch = curl_init();

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: OAuth ' .$auth;
    curl_setopt($twitch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($twitch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/user");

    curl_exec($twitch);
?>
</pre>

<?php }; ?>
```

When I attempt to run this section of code, I get some errors:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 08 Aug 2015 13:43:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 89
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 401 Unauthorized
X-API-Version: 3
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm='TwitchTV'
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Request-Id: 4bc2e0bfadf6817366b4eb19ab5751bf
X-Runtime: 0.007862
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Varnish: 1641121794
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-MH-Cache: rails-varnish-5cb970; M

{"error":"Unauthorized","status":401,"message":"Token invalid or missing required scope"}
```

But I am unsure on how to fix this problem as, to me, it seems I am/have done everything that the documentation says to do...

How should I go about fixing this issue?

**Edit:**

It seems to work if I request using my [twitch username](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/users.md#example-request):

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' \
-X GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_user1
```

My Code for using the username:

```
<?php
$auth = urlencode($_GET['code']);
$twitch = curl_init();

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json';
#$headers[] = 'Authorization: OAuth ' .$auth;
curl_setopt($twitch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , $headers);
curl_setopt($twitch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/...");

curl_exec($twitch);
?>
```

But I wouldn't know the user's username unless I get it from the statement which is producing an error and store it in a database.

**Edit:**

Reading into the documentation abit more, it requires the scope as well as the access token. I have been able to get this:

Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json
    [1] => Authorization: OAuth code=scn89zerug002sr6r95z9ngbxmd0d2&scope=user_read+channel_read+channel_subscriptions+user_subscriptions+channel_check_subscription
)
```

But I still get the error...

**Edit:**

So I read through the documentation **EVEN MORE** and now I have gotten to this:

```
class twitch {
    var $base_url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/";
    var $client_id = "...";
    var $client_secret = "...";
    var $return_url = "...";
    var $scope_array = array('user_read','channel_read','channel_subscriptions','user_subscriptions','channel_check_subscription');

    public function get_access_token($code,$state) {
        $ch = curl_init($this->base_url . "oauth2/token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $fields = array(
             'client_id' => $this->client_id,
             'client_secret' => $this->client_secret,
             'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
             'redirect_uri' => $this->redirect_url,
             'code' => $code
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $response = json_decode($data, true);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo "<pre>".print_r($this->redirect_url,true)."</pre>";
        echo "<pre>".print_r($response,true)."</pre>";

        return $response["access_token"];
    }
};

$auth = new twitch();
print_r($auth->get_access_token($_GET['code'],$_GET['state']));
```

But this time there is **another** error, saying that my `'redirect_uri' => $this->redirect_url` is different to the one which is held by twitch.

```
Array
(
    [error] => Bad Request
    [status] => 400
    [message] => Parameter redirect_uri does not match registered URI
)
```

I have even copied and pasted from the twitch website to my variable and the other way around, I still get the same error... Now I'm even more stuck, but at least a step closer.

Comment: You'd need `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` for setting your custom Authorization: request headers. (The likenamed `CURLOPT_HEADER` is mostly just for debugging.)

Comment: @mario, hey! thanks for the comment, `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` hides the debugging, it still doesn't solve my issue. But thanks! I'll keep this in mind when I move forward :)

Comment: I think you want `.urlencode($auth);`

Comment: You can enable `_HEADER` still. But mostly set `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` first to see what's actually going on. ([PHP cURL custom headers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8115683))

Comment: @Mihai, Hi there - I have altered `$auth = $_GET['code'];` to `$auth = urlencode($_GET['code']);`. But I still get the same issue.

Comment: Try hardcoding directly $auth=3ofbaoidzkym72ntjua1gmrr66o0nd

Comment: @Mihai - Hi, that doesn't seem to work either, even though I used the code that was generated with my account when I authorized my website

Comment: @hello give me a minute, I'll make a script and demo :)

Comment: @sourRaspberri, alright - have a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right I'm going to do this with you as I do it :d So far I've been able to get one user, the reason you're getting errors is because you're not setting any curl options. I taught myself using this https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-curlsamples/blob/master/execute_all_calls.php which I found MASSIVELY helpful when learning curl. The code itself is basic but it's so easy to read. I managed to understand it and make it 100% more complicated :D

First things first, I'll show you how I got the test user. 
What you want to do is set the options, I'll keep to the simple method first.

The 2 methods are `CURLOPT_HEADER` and `CURL_RETURNTRANSFER`. Your url you can set with the init function.

```
$twitch=curl_init('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_user1');
curl_setopt($twitch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json'));//must be an array.
curl_setopt($twitch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$result=curl_exec($twitch);
$info=curl_getinfo($twitch);
print_r($result);
```

This will get you your test user and hopefully show you a little bit about what you're doing wrong. If you wanted to use the array method, then you must use your curl options as the array key so that the set function know what to set what as. (don't ask me how it all technically works :S)

I'll update to show you how to get an authorisation and data once I've worked it out. But the basic principles are you need to send post data and set `CURLOPT_POST` to true and include the postdata `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` which must be a json array as your application requires json I believe?

Anyway the array:

```
curl_set_opts($twitch,array(CURLOPT_HEADER=>array('Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json',CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=true));
```

Seeing as you already know how to authorise a user I'll skip that bit, although I'd recommend using something a little more secure than a `$_GET`. Maybe a session variable would be a bit better.

To get a specific user using the Auth that is returned. You want to do something like this: (Sorry I can't test it myself, I don't have a twitch dev account)

```
$twitch=curl_init('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/user');
curl_setopt($twitch,CURLOPT_HEADER,array('Accept: application/cvd.twitchtv.v3+json','Authorization: OAuth '.$_SESSION['token']));
curl_setopt($twitch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$result=curl_exec($twitch);
print_r($result);
//don't forget to close! 
curl_close($twitch);
$user=json_decode($result);

echo$user->display_name;
```

That should work although I have no idea how you're getting a oAuth token lol

if you wanted to be a really cool programmer 8| I'd recommend doing some classes for this. Like this

```
class twitch{
    private$token,$twitch,$url="http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/";
    protected$code,$state,$report;
    private static$details;
    public function __construct($code,$state){
        $this->code=$code;
        $this->state=$state;
        self::$details=(object)array('client_id'=>'id','client_secret'=>'secret','return_url'=>'redirect');
        $result=$this->makeCall('oauth2/token',true);
        print_r($result);
    }
    protected function makeCall($extention,$auth=false,$object=true){
        $this->twitch=curl_init($this->url.$extention);
        //$opts=array(CURLOPT_)
        if($auth!==false){
            $opts=array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>true,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,CURLOPT_POST=>true,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>json_encode(array('client_id'=>self::$details->client_id,'client_secret'=>self::$details->client_secret,'grant_type'=>'authorization_code','code'=>$this->code,'redirect_uri'=>self::$details->return_url)));
        }else{
            $opts=array(CURLOPT_HEADER=>array('Accept: application/cvd.twitchtv.v3+json','Authorization: OAuth '.$this->token),CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true);
        }
        curl_setopt_array($this->twitch,$opts);
        $result=curl_exec($this->twitch);
        $this->report=array('info'=>curl_getinfo($this->twitch),'error'=>curl_error($this->twitch));
        curl_close($this->twitch);
        return($object===true)?json_decode($result):$result;
    }
    protected function userDetails(){
        return$this->makeCall('user');
    }
    public function user(){
        return$this->userDetails();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the response, although this doesn't seem to be quite how it works, it's still helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @hello ahhh ok, yea it's a bit of a strange set up? Do you have to go to the url to get a response? Then use the OAuth token it supplies within the redirect url? Mad! You might want to check the last two code examples then. I'm unsure how the auth works so the last example may not work but it'll give you a good idea of how to build to send a receive data. If you're still not seeing a response. Maybe try using `curl_getinfo()` and `curl_error()` to see what errors there are.

Comment: @hello see you're getting there :p make sure the urls are 100% exact. Including http:// etc.

Comment: @hello ok I understand how to get an auth now :) Would you like me to adjust my answer? :)

Comment: Sure! Although I am unsure why the `redirect_uri` isn't the same as the one saved with twitch, even though I copied and pasted them. so they _should be the same_. once it stops giving out that error, then the auth_token should work.

Comment: @hello no idea, Maybe try seeing if you're setting the wrong variable or something? Ok I'll redo my answer :)

Comment: @hello :) cool! well done! I've updated my class so that you can send multiple requests from one user. makes life easier :) might be helpful to you sometime I dunno lol