# Check if account exists by email (facebook)

Tags: php

How can I check if facebook account exists by typing email?
For example, if i go to http://mysite.pl/fb/?email=email@gmail.com and if account with this email exists on facebook, it returns "true", if not, returns "false".
Code I tried:

```
if(isset($_GET["email"])) {
    $url = file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/search/results/?q='.$_GET["email"]);
    echo '<pre>'.$url.'</pre>';

}
```

It's not working, returns info that my browser is not supported by facebook.

Comment: *"It's not working, returns info that my browser is not supported by facebook."* - As it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something Facebook is going to enjoy you doing. If you want to try anyway, you need to set your request header to something that they'll think is a normal web browser. This will mean using `cURL` instead of just `file_get_contents()`.

See this question for more information: [PHP cURL custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers)