# Getting Json from API with AccountKey and Accept

Tags: php, curl

I am new to PHP and have been trying to access to the API for the past 2 hours. Everytime i request for the json object, it kept giving me null. I am sure i filled up the URL and Accountkey correctly. Can comeone please correct me if i did anything wrong with the code below. Thank you.

```
<?php
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://urlxxxxxxxx.com');

   $header = array(
   'AccountKey:' => 'xxxx',
   'Accept:' => 'application/json');

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   $obj = json_decode($result);
   curl_close($ch);

   print "<pre>";
   print_r($obj);
   print "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Do you confirm `$result` is a valid json string? If it is `false`, check what `curl_error($ch)` returns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cURL custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers)

Comment: @ZhenHui any output after fixing `key=>value` pattern to `key:value` ?

Comment: yes the output is what i got back from the API which is the data i need. Format is in json type

Comment: "json type" is not necessarily a valid parsable json. `json_decode` returns false when it fails to parse the string. Check what [json-last-error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) returns, or try to check the result in a json validator online.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `CURL` http headers like this, not as php array `key=>value` pattern.

```
 $header = array(
   'AccountKey: xxxx',
   'Accept:application/json'
 );
```