# Set request header with values before calling a API url in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, httprequest, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to get this to work.

http://www.dezrez.com/webguide/rezifeed.asp

I need to set the request header with certain values before calling the api url. How do i go about setting request header and calling the url after its been set in cakephp? Please let me know if further info is required.

Thanks

EDIT

Found this link http://lennaert.nu/2013/12/01/how-to-use-httpsocket-instead-of-curl-in-cakephp-2/ - httpsocket was what i used and it worked fine!

Comment: please show what have you tried so far

Comment: @arilia please see the edit. I think i'm quite a bit away from the solution...

Comment: I'm guessing here, but from what I understand, you want to call external URL in your controller and retrieve some data. If so, you need to do it using, eg, curl: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php and set headers like is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers

Comment: Great thanks, will give that a go.

Comment: `$_SERVER` gives you information about the request that your code is currently handling. It has nothing whatsoever to do with any requests your code might make to other servers.

Comment: Yep, i was looking in wrong section. Got it sorted now using httpsocket! Thanks