# add basic authorization to php curl script

Tags: php

How do I add basic authorization to my below php script? I am trying to send data to an API

```
$ch = curl_init();
$token = 'eyJpZCI6MTExOCwiZW52IXXXXXXXXJzaWQiOjYsImFsZyI6IkhTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbkBtaW5leDXXXXXXXTAsImV4cCI6MTU0ODk0ODgxMH0.owTm-ItzXnpqVSFbXXXXXXXXXX';
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token; // Prepare the authorisation token

$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "https://api.endpoint.com",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        'From' => 'HI',
        'To' => '024XXXXXXX',
        'Content' => 'hello there'
    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result
```

Comment: its not auth basic, thats a jwt, so should be used in header

Comment: please how do i do it? i'm new to php

Comment: @developer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work (I'm not sure, as I never used Authorization)...

```
$ch = curl_init();
$token = 'eyJpZCI6MTExOCwiZW52IXXXXXXXXJzaWQiOjYsImFsZyI6IkhTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbkBtaW5leDXXXXXXXTAsImV4cCI6MTU0ODk0ODgxMH0.owTm-ItzXnpqVSFbXXXXXXXXXX';

$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "https://api.endpoint.com",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        'From' => 'HI',
        'To' => '024XXXXXXX',
        'Content' => 'hello there'
    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$token
));
curl_close($ch);
echo $result
```

That's it?