# How to send data in http headers in php for calling another server Api

Tags: php, http-headers

I have to call third party API which I need to send data in headers  I am trying in cURL.

Is there any method to send data without curl on third party server which receiving on headers parameters.

This is what am trying but not succeed:

```
$MobileNo=$_POST['MobileNo'];
$SMSText=$_POST['SMSText'];

$remarks=$_POST['remarks'];
$RequestNo=$_POST['RequestNo'];
$headers = array
(
    'MobileNo', $MobileNo,
    'RequestNo', $RequestNo,
    'SMSText', $SMSText,
    'Content-Type: application/text'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/api/SendEnglishSMS' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

I want to send data as well as receive the response from the third server request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cURL custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers)

Comment: Shouldn't the headers be: `'MobileNo: ' .  $MobileNo,`? As it is now, you're creating one header with `MobileNo` and then another header with the value of `$MobileNo`.

Comment: I need to create three header one for MobileNo, RequestNo and SMSText

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code. Hope, it will help you.

```
$headers = array
(
    'MobileNo:'.$MobileNo,
    'RequestNo:'.$RequestNo,
    'SMSText:'.$SMSText,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
```