# how to pass a secret key as an authorization header in API call

Tags: javascript, php, api

Please how can I pass a secret key as an authorization header in API call?

See the script below:

```
 <?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$postData = $_POST;
$publicKey = $postData['publicKey'];
$bvn_number = $postData['bvn'];

//initializing
$ch = curl_init();

//used to send the request to the Api endpoint
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.paystack.co/bank/resolve_bvn".$bvn_number."?seckey=".$secretKey);

//return instead of outputing directly
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//whether to include the header in the output set to false here

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//execute the response

$output = curl_exec($ch);

//check for errors

if($output === FALSE){
echo "Invalid bvn number:" . curl_error($ch);
}

//close and free up the handel

curl_close($ch);

//display the output

print_r($output);

?>
```

Error message:

> Error: { "status": false, "message": "No Authorization Header was
>   found" }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cURL custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers)

Comment: `$url = 'https://api.paystack.co/bank/resolve?account_number=0022728151&bank_code=063';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer sk_live_a....'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  
echo($result);`

Use this. Put secret key hardcoded in the Authorization Bearer

Answer (score 2):

If it requires authorization bearer you have to add the word `Bearer` to the authentication header before the token or secret.

Here an example.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer'. $token));
```

example from reference:

```
GET /resource HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM
```

[Reference](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html)

Comment: Still not working, I replace the line code with what you sent but still getting error message: { "status": false, "message": "Format is Authorization Bearer [secret key]" }

Answer (score 0):

You are puting the secret key in the query string.

change the line below:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

to the code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: ' . $secretKey));
```

Comment: i tried it but see error message below: { "status": false, "message": "Format is Authorization Bearer [secret key]" }

Comment: so write:
```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $secretKey));
```

Comment: I use: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: Bearer $secretKey"]); and its now working perfectly, thank you