# Fetch xml data from API response

Tags: php, xml

Request:

```
$headers = array(   'Content-Type:application/xml'  ); 
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com',
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_USERPWD=>'test:test',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $XMLData
        ));
        $APIResponse = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

And I get this response from an API

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: ----
X-AspNet-Version: -----
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: ---- GMT
Content-Length: 100

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.example.com"><ID>12345</ID></response>
```

I want to fetch ID from xml ID tag. How can I get that in my php code?

Comment: PHP has classes/functions for reading XML data in a structured way. What have you researched, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this -> $xml = simplexml_load_string($APIResponse); but its empty.

Comment: Ok. So, what was the exact content of `$APIResponse`? Is it just the XML, or the whole text you've shown above? Please make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
 showing how you actually fetch and process the data.

Comment: Content in question is what all the content that I am getting in response var -> $APIResponse. I need to extract /read XML from it

Comment: how exactly are you getting that data into PHP then? Most libraries which handle HTTP requests will give you the response data and the headers in separate variables. That's why I asked you to show your code.

Comment: I update my question, please take a look on it.. thanks

Comment: I think CURLOPT_HEADER doesn't do what you think it does. That doesn't include your _request_ headers in the request, it sets whether the _response_ headers are included in the output or not. set `CURLOPT_HEADER => 0` and your problem should go away - then only the XML response should be included in the output from curl_exec.  At this page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php the manual described what this option does.

Comment: The way you set custom _request_ headers is shown here (and in many other examples online): https://stackoverflow.com/a/8115709/5947043

Comment: Great, I added it as a proper answer below, so please feel free to mark it as "accepted" - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the HTTP header data included within your response from cURL, which is making it hard to extract the XML part.

However this is happening due to a simple misunderstanding - the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option doesn't do what you think it does.

That doesn't include your *request* headers in the request (as your code seems to be trying to do), instead it sets an option telling cURL whether or not the *response* headers should be included in the main output or not.  If you set

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => 0
```

in your code, your problem should go away - then only the response body (in your case, just the XML) will included in the output from curl_exec.

In the meantime, if you need to set custom HTTP headers in your *request*, you can do it via the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option - a detailed example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers/8115709#8115709) and in many other places online.

P.S. Admittedly these option names are not, in themselves, very clear about the difference between them, but the [PHP manual](https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) does describe what they do in more detail.