# The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, curl

I have been working on setting up the [frase api](https://docs.frase.io/article/214-process-url). and created the following curl snippet.

```
<?php


    $url = 'http://api.frase.io/api/v1/process_url';
    //The data you want to send via POST
    
    $fields = ['url' => 'https://firstsiteguide.com/best-gaming-blogs/', 'token' =>  "dd528796a9924dae9962bc5bd7ccdb20"];

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);              
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($fields));
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0');
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      
      if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
            echo "<br/>CURL ERROR: ". $error_msg ."<br/>";
      }else{
          print "curl response is:" . $response ;
      }

      
      curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

I am not sure why, But I am receiving the following error for the same

> The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request

Can help me identify what part of code I am missing or doing wrong. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You need to add the token as a header field, according to the frase doc. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers

Comment: @DonR Thanks for the help! added the token in headers still the response is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the `token` as a body parameter instead of a `header`. The body parameter needs to be sent as a `JSON encoded string` as mentioned on the API documentation page. Also, you need to remove or at least increase the cURL timeout value as it takes time to fetch, process and return a value from the API end. Note that the API will return the response in `JSON format`.

So, the complete code should be as:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://api.frase.io/api/v1/process_url'; //The endpoint url you want to send data via POST

$headers = ['token: dd528796a9924dae9962bc5bd7ccdb20']; // add this line, headers

$fields = ['url' => 'https://firstsiteguide.com/best-gaming-blogs/']; // modify this line, body

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); // add this line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields)); // modify this
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0');

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch))
{
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    echo "<br/>CURL ERROR: " . $error_msg . "<br/>";
}
else
{
    print($response);
    
    // $values = json_decode($response, true); // this is an array with all the values
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```